# How to load an entity definition?

Tags: 8, entities

I need to load an entity definition to add a constraint and test it, I found that this is possible with the following code:

```
$manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
$entity_definition = $manager->getEntityType('node');
$entity_definition->addConstraint(‘name’);
```

But I wonder if this is the correct way or if exists another.

Comment: Are you using that code in a test? If yes, I don't see anything wrong with using the entity update service.

Comment: Differently, if the code is not used inside `hook_update_N()`, one of the hooks that allows to alter an entity definition should be used.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes I will use the code in a test to test a constraint added to the node entity.

Comment: @kiamlaluno but this is the only way to get the entity definition or there is another service to do it?

Comment: To update an entity definition, that is the service you should use.

Answer (score 0):

The only case where you want to work with entityDefinitionUpdateManager() in update and post update hooks, to update an entity type definition on existing installations to the one defined on the annotation.

To add a constraint to an entity type that's not yours use hook_entity_type_alter()

Comment: Thanks I'm using the hook_entity_type_alter() hook to add the constraint but to test it the use of entityDefinitionUpdateManager is the only way that I found to add the constraint and test it, you can take a look inside the test file at https://cgit.drupalcode.org/onlyone/tree/tests/src/Kernel/OnlyOneConstraintValidatorTest.php#n46